# Does an open immersion "cut out" points surviving finite descent?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, arithmetic-geometry

Let $X$ be a smooth affine curve over a number field $k$, and let $C$ be its smooth compactification. Let $i:X(\mathbb{A}_k) \rightarrow C(\mathbb{A}_k)$ be the induced morphism of adelic points by the open immersion $X \hookrightarrow C$.

Here $i$ is injective, and we obviously have $X(\mathbb{A}_k)^\mathrm{f-cov} \subset i^{-1}(C(\mathbb{A}_k)^\mathrm{f-cov})$, where $X(\mathbb{A}_k)^\mathrm{f-cov}$ denotes the set of adelic points surviving all torsors $Y \rightarrow X$ under finite etale group schemes, same for $C$. I'm wondering if the reverse inclusion holds in this case.

In other words, to what extent do we have
$$(P_v) \in X(\mathbb{A}_k)^\mathrm{f-cov} \iff i(P_v) \in C(\mathbb{A}_k)^\mathrm{f-cov}?$$

**Motivation.** Similar phenomenon has been observed in other cases, such as the following:

1. (Brauer-Manin obstruction). When $C$ is a smooth projective geometrically connected curve of genus $\geq 1$ with a $k$-point inducing an embedding $i:C \hookrightarrow J$ into its Jacobian variety $J$, one has a surjective morphism $\mathrm{Br}(J) \rightarrow \mathrm{Br}(C)$ and $$(P_v) \in C(\mathbb{A}_k)^\mathrm{Br} \iff i(P_v) \in J(\mathbb{A}_k)^\mathrm{Br}.$$
2. (Finite abelian descent obstruction). When $Z$ is a finite subscheme of a smooth projective geometrically connected curve $C$ of genus $\geq 1$, with embedding $i: Z \hookrightarrow C$, one has
   $$(P_v) \in Z(\mathbb{A}_k)^\mathrm{f-ab} \iff i(P_v) \in C(\mathbb{A}_k)^\mathrm{f-ab}.$$

**References**.

1. For the first example, it's Corollary 2.6 in *The $d$-primary Brauer-Manin Obstruction for curves* by Creutz, Viray and Voloch.
2. For the second example, it's Theorem 8.2 of *Finite descent and rational points on curves* by Stoll.

**EDIT.** By the examples given above, I would like to add that I'm interested in the case where $X$ has genus at least $1$.

Comment: When you write, "surviving all torsors", do you mean that it equals the image of an element in the Brauer subset of the set of adelic points of the torsor?  Anyway, this seems to fail for $k=\mathbb{Q}$ and $X=\mathbb{G}_{m,k} = \text{Spec}\ k[t,t^{-1}]$.  Let $\ell$ an odd prime and let $w$ be the corresponding valuation of $k$. Let $(a,b)$ be a quaternion algebra over $k$ whose invariant in $\text{Br}(k_{w}) \cong \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ is a generator.  Let $(a,t)$ be the corresponding Brauer class over $X$. Let $P_v=1$ for $v\neq w$ and let $P_{w} = b$.

Comment: @JasonStarr Regarding surviving a torsor, I'm using the notion introduced by Stoll in the paper cited above. Fix a torsor $f: Y \rightarrow X$ under finite etale $G$, then $(P_v)$ survives $f$ if its image in $\prod_v H^1(k_v,G)$ (where the evaluation at each $v$ is given by pull-back of $f$ to a torsor over $\mathrm{Spec}\,k_v$) comes from the localization map $H^1(k,G) \rightarrow \prod _v H^1(k_v,G)$. Is this the same as your definition? I would like to know how is the Brauer set involved in this, otherwise your (counter)example looks completely new to me!

Comment: @JasonStarr Also, maybe I should've mentioned this in my post, but the examples cited consider curves of genus at least $1$, do you think it would play a part in making the result hold? Actually we can rephrase the problem as such: does there exist an adelic point $(P_v)$ in the affine curve $X$ that does not survive at least one $X$-torsor under some finite etale $G$, such that its image $i(P_v)$ in $C(\mathbb{A}_k)$ survives all $C$-torsors under ALL finite etale $G$? I'm hoping for a negative answer in the case of genus $\geq 1$ but I'm not sure how to proceed.

Comment: You can easily modify my example to that definition (in fact, that is where my example started).  The "squaring" endomomorphism of $\mathbb{G}_{m,k}$ is a torsor for the finite flat group scheme $\mu_n$.  By Hilbert's Theorem 90, the group of torsors for a field $K$ (e.g., $K=k$ or $K=k_v$) is $K^\times/ (K^\times)^2$.  For the adelic point above with $b=\ell$, by the product formula of $p$-adic norms, the element of $k^\times/(k^\times)^2$ is the congruence class of $\ell$.  This contradicts Chebotarev's density theorem for $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{\ell})/\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: @JasonStarr It's quite a handful of information for me, I'll have a long hard think about it, thank you! Anyway, I think the group of torsors you mentioned above is $H^1(k,\mu_n)$ which has to be $k^\times / (k^\times )^n$, not $k^\times /(k^\times )^2$.

Comment: In my comment, the integer is $n=2$.